# How to use either Policy based and Role based in Asp.Net Core controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I setup my authorization in controller like this:

```
[Authorize(Role= "Admin", Policy = "EmployeeOnly")]
public IActionResult VacationBalance()
{
    return View();
}

//configure services..
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
        options.AddPolicy("EmployeeOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber"));
});
```

Now, when i logged in as an admin user. Meaning i have "Admin" role. I expected that i can access the VacationBalance controller since i have admin role. But unfortunately i can't access the page and i got a forbidden response.
I am expected that this controller can be accessed either by an "Admin" role or "EmployeeOnly" claim.
Does it work that way?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will make only user who has `EmployeeNumber` and `Admin` role can access the `VacationBalance` action, to achieve your requirement , you can create another policy to check :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EmployeeOrAdmin", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {

            var isEmployee = context.User.HasClaim(c=>c.Type== "EmployeeNumber");
            var roles= context.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();
            var isAdmin = roles.Any(str => str.Value.Equals("Admin"));

            return isEmployee || isAdmin ;
        });
    });
});
```

Then apply the policy on your protected actions :

```
[Authorize( Policy = "EmployeeOrAdmin")]
```

Comment: alright got it. I thought i can just add it that way without setting a new policy.